# Can not make path to the file in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsbundle

I try to open the file in Swift. For it I create the file path. It doesn't work.

```
maaaacy:~ $ pwd
/Users/tsypa
maaaacy:~ $ cat a.txt
test
maaaacy:~ $ ./a.swift 
nil!
maaaacy:~ $
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/xcrun swift 

import Foundation

var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("a", ofType: "txt", inDirectory: "/Users/tsypa")
if let file = filePath {
        println("file path \(file)")
        // reading content of the file will be here
} else {
        println("nil!")
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The problem is that the file doesn't belong to a 'bundle'. Use an [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead (or `NSURL` if you only require a reference to the path of the resource).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Swift REPL, the `NSBundle.mainBundle()`'s path actually points to:

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources
```

You may have to use [**NSFileManager**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html) instead:

```
let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if manager.fileExistsAtPath("/Users/tsypa/a.txt") {
    // file exists, read
} else {
    // file doesn't exist
}
```

---

**Note:** You can actually automatically expand tilde in the path to avoid hardcoding the full user's home path:

```
"~/a.txt".stringByExpandingTildeInPath // prints /Users/<your user>/a.txt
```