# Swift: How to expand a tilde in a path String

Tags: swift, path, nsfilemanager, home-directory, tilde-expansion

How can I expand a path String with a tilde in Swift? I have a string like `"~/Desktop"` and I'd like to use this path with the `NSFileManager` methods, which requires the tilde to be expanded to `"/Users/<myuser>/Desktop"`.

(This question with a clear problem statement doesn't exist yet, this should be easily findable. Some similar but not satisfying questions are [Can not make path to the file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626896/can-not-make-path-to-the-file-in-swift/25627019#25627019), [Simple way to read local file using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846459/simple-way-to-read-local-file-using-swift), [Tilde-based Paths in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675852/tilde-based-paths-in-objective-c/1675867#1675867))

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Tilde expansion

#### Swift 1

```
"~/Desktop".stringByExpandingTildeInPath
```

#### Swift 2

```
NSString(string: "~/Desktop").stringByExpandingTildeInPath
```

#### Swift 3

```
NSString(string: "~/Desktop").expandingTildeInPath
```

### Home Directory

Additionally you can get the home directory like this (returns a `String`/`String?`):

```
NSHomeDirectory()
NSHomeDirectoryForUser("<User>")
```

In Swift 3 and OS X 10.12 it's also possible to use this (returns a `URL`/`URL?`):

```
FileManager.default().homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
FileManager.default().homeDirectory(forUser: "<User>")
```

Edit: In Swift 3.1 this got changed to `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser`

Comment: +, especially for self-answering

Comment: `FileManager.default()` would be simply `FileManager.default` in Swift 3.1

Comment: So, the Swift 3.1 "~/Desktop" equivalent could be `let homeDir = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` followed by
`let desktopDir = homeDir.appendingPathComponent("Desktop", isDirectory: true)`

Comment: When using the path in a URL (like `URL(fileURLWithPath: "~/Desktop").path`), this results in `"/private/tmp/~/Desktop"`

Comment: @NickK9 I am no longer using Swift and am therefore unable to provide updates regarding this. You can update my answer to provide an update

Answer (score 5):

Return string:

```
func expandingTildeInPath(_ path: String) -> String {
    return path.replacingOccurrences(of: "~", with: FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.path)
}
```

Return URL:

```
func expandingTildeInPath(_ path: String) -> URL {
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: path.replacingOccurrences(of: "~", with: FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser.path))
}
```

If OS less than 10.12, replace

```
FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
```

with

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 Extension**

```
public extension String {

    public var expandingTildeInPath: String {
        return NSString(string: self).expandingTildeInPath
    }

}
```

Comment: note - you have to be really careful if using this from a sandboxed app. You'll probably end up with the wrong path...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that does not depend on the `NSString` class and works with Swift 4:

```
func absURL ( _ path: String ) -> URL {
    guard path != "~" else {
        return FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
    }
    guard path.hasPrefix("~/") else { return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)  }

    var relativePath = path
    relativePath.removeFirst(2)
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: relativePath,
        relativeTo: FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
    )
}

func absPath ( _ path: String ) -> String {
    return absURL(path).path
}
```

Test code:

```
print("Path: \(absPath("~"))")
print("Path: \(absPath("/tmp/text.txt"))")
print("Path: \(absPath("~/Documents/text.txt"))")
```

The reason for splitting the code into two methods is that nowadays you rather want URLs when working with files and folders and not string paths (all new APIs use URLs for paths).

By the way, if you just want to know the absolute path of `~/Desktop` or `~/Documents` and similar folders, there's an even easier way for that:

```
let desktop = FileManager.default.urls(
    for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask
)[0]
print("Desktop: \(desktop.path)")

let documents = FileManager.default.urls(
    for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask
)[0]
print("Documents: \(documents.path)")
```

Comment: @Alexander In terms of NSURL `~` is problematic as all directories must end with `/` as indicator that they are directories (otherwise using such an URL as baseURL will have undesired effects for example) and not files  E.g. `file:///var/xxx`, what is xxx? You can't know. Without further knowledge NSURL will assume it is a file but in case of `file:///var/xxx/` it knows that `xxx` is a directory and a trailing `/` is legal for all file APIs on Mac (including BSD and Cocoa). If you need to resolve just `~`, call `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` and make result an URL.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. That's a useful convention to uphold

Comment: @Alexander I will update the code and just treat a plain `~` as a special case. I think that is easier than trying to find a solution that always works correctly.

Comment: [`NSURL.standardizingPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1414302-standardizingpath) should be able to handle all this correctly, but for some reason, wasn't imported into `URL`.