# "Bash like" paths to NSURL or Foundation path

Tags: swift, nsurl, foundation

In most command line tools, paths to files can be specified using formats like those: `../someFile`, `~/anotherFile`, `/foo/bar`. How can I init a valid Swift `URL` or (Foundation) path from such a path?

**EDIT:**
Maybe a code example is clearer, say I want to init a String from path and I have a `foo` file in my user directory, doing this:

```
try String(contentsOfFile: "~/foo")
```

Doesn't work (error is file does not exist)

Comment: `init(fileURLWithPath path: String, relativeTo base: URL?)` for the last one?

Comment: @Larme Hum... if I'm right the last one isn't a relative URL (it just specifies a ressource placed at the root of the current disk in the /foo folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173050/swift-how-to-expand-a-tilde-in-a-path-string

Comment: @MartinR - that answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, you can do :

```
let str = "~/Documents"
// NSString has a function for decoding this, not available to String:
let str2 = (str as NSString).standardizingPath as String 

// Swift deprecated the String path manipulation functions,
// but supplies them as part of NSURL:
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: str)
let url2 = url.standardizedFileURL // Expands the URL
```